# WPF-ContextMenu - how to Disable background change on mouse over or focus

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

its my first question in StackOverFlow ,

I have a text box , when clicking on,it shows a context menu , I have some control (user control or ..) in context menu.

everything is ok except in mouse over , all my controls get focus and their background change to blue , its so awful,
another problem , in context menu , there is an vertical line , and an Icon place in left of it , How Can I remove it ?

C# code :

```
private void textBox1_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = textBox1;
        textBox1.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        textBox1.Focus();
}
```

and XAML Code :

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,55,0,0"
Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
Width="120" MouseDown="textBox1_MouseDown" 
GotMouseCapture="textBox1_GotMouseCapture"
ContextMenuService.HasDropShadow="False" 
ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True" 
TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged">
<TextBox.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu Name="ctm" Placement="Relative" 
    Focusable="False" HasDropShadow="False" 
    VerticalOffset="23" HorizontalOffset="0">
    <StackPanel Margin="0" >
        <TextBox Text="testing..." Name="testing"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>                    
</ContextMenu>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

thanks to all .

Comment: can you post your complete code? XAML + event handlers

Comment: its the complete code , when I click on TextBox1 , a ContextMenu (and its child s ) will appeared.when I move mouse over the ContextMenu ,it get highlighted.I dont want to use ContextMenu its self , I use it for searching purpose , when user click on TextBox1 , a search form will appear in context menu.
I dont want usercontrol or form in ContextMenu to become highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

one way to solve your "color" problem. you can override the systemcolors to get the behavior you want.
just choose the SystemColor you need to override.

```
<ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
   </ContextMenu.Resources>
```

EDIT:

i use the following for my contextmenu to set the selectioncolor to transparent and the selected item to green foreground.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="DarkGreen"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Dear Blindmeis , but it doest work , is it because of SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey  , the ContextMenu may use other color for highlighting.

Comment: yes you have to choose the right SystemColors.XXX. SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey was just an example

Comment: how can I find the correct SystemColors.XXX  ? its the pic : http://oi56.tinypic.com/2dgkzld.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As of blindmeis answer, the problem is the HighlightBrushKey.
To get other possible solutions you can lookup the wpf source code now.
For the menuitem this is

https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/03043efa30c4f13ab630368e9ffa0e9558519f9e/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/Themes/XAML/MenuItem.xaml#L1278

with the following xaml

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}, ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey}"
                     TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border Name="Bd"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="17"
                                      Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!-- Glyph -->
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                  Margin="4,0,6,0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  ContentSource="Icon"/>
                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel"
                      Margin="4,0,6,0"
                      Visibility="Hidden"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                      FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                      Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}"/>
                <ContentPresenter
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                           Margin="5,2,0,2"
                           DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon"
                     Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

for your problem you can build your own Controltemplate and remove the triggers and GlypPanel ect.